# Store ENUM value into database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, spring-data-jpa

I wan to use ENUM to map values into database table rows:

*BusinessCustomersSearchParams:*

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class BusinessCustomersSearchParams {

    private String title;

    private List<String> status;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

Specification:

```java
@Override
public Page<BusinessCustomersFullDTO> findBusinessCustomers(BusinessCustomersSearchParams params, Pageable pageable)
{
    Specification<BusinessCustomers> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (params.getTitle() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("description")), "%" + params.getTitle().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }

        final List<String> statuses = Optional.ofNullable(params.getStatus()).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
        if (statuses != null && !statuses.isEmpty()){
            List<BusinessCustomersStatus> statusesAsEnum = statuses.stream()
                .map(status -> BusinessCustomersStatus.fromStatus(status))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                ;

            predicates.add(root.get("status").in(statusesAsEnum));
        }

        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    };
    return businessCustomersService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(businessCustomersMapper::toFullDTO);
}
```

AttributeConverter:

```java
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class BusinessCustomersStatusAttributeConverter
    implements AttributeConverter<BusinessCustomersStatus, String> {

  public String convertToDatabaseColumn( BusinessCustomersStatus value ) {
    if ( value == null ) {
      return null;
    }

    return value.getStatus();
  }

  public BusinessCustomersStatus convertToEntityAttribute( String value ) {
    if ( value == null ) {
      return null;
    }

    return BusinessCustomersStatus.fromStatus( value );
  }

}
```

Enum:

```java
package org.merchant.database.service.businesscustomers;

public enum BusinessCustomersStatus {
    A("active"),
    O("onboarding"),
    N("not_verified"),
    V("verified"),
    S("suspended"),
    I("inactive");

    private String status;

    BusinessCustomersStatus(String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public static BusinessCustomersStatus fromStatus(String status) {
        switch (status) {
            case "active": {
                return A;
            }

            case "onboarding": {
                return O;
            }

            case "not_verified": {
                return NV;
            }

            case "verified": {
                return V;
            }

            case "suspended": {
                return S;
            }

            case "inactive": {
                return I;
            }

            default: {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    String.format("Unkhown status: '%s'", status)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "business_customers")
public class BusinessCustomers implements Serializable {
   
    ..........
    @Convert( converter = BusinessCustomersStatusAttributeConverter.class )
    private BusinessCustomersStatus status;
    ......
}
```

Full code example: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Search_specification_POC

I send http query with params `list?size=5&page=0&status=active,suspended` and I get result with capital letters "status": "ACTIVE".

I wan to search and get status from FE for status using `status=active` but store into database row field only symbol A.

How I can store into database the ENUM key A?

Comment: Usually to save the enumeration's "name" in the database the following annotation is used `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` over the enum property `private BusinessCustomersStatus status;` in the Entity. You created the custom converter `BusinessCustomersStatusAttributeConverter` for what reason?

Comment: Just change `ACTIVE("active")` to `ACTIVE("ACTIVE")`, and similarly for all the other elements. Or get rid of the `status` member altogether, as you don't seem to want to use it, and use the `name()` attribute instead. You've gone to a lot of trouble to create a mapping you don't seem to actually want. Why?

Comment: I have updated the post. Can you advice, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to store the actual enumeration value in the database, you can do two things.

One, as suggested by @PetarBivolarski, modify the method `convertToDatabaseColumn` in `AttributeConverter` and return `value.name()` instead of `value.getStatus()`. But please, be aware that in addition you will need to update the `convertToEntityAttribute` as well to take into account that change:

```java
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class BusinessCustomersStatusAttributeConverter
    implements AttributeConverter<BusinessCustomersStatus, String> {

  public String convertToDatabaseColumn( BusinessCustomersStatus value ) {
    if ( value == null ) {
      return null;
    }

    return value.name();
  }

  public BusinessCustomersStatus convertToEntityAttribute( String value ) {
    if ( value == null ) {
      return null;
    }

    return BusinessCustomersStatus.valueOf( value );
  }

}
```

If you think about it, a more straightforward solution will be just keep the `status` field as `@Enumerated`:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "business_customers")
public class BusinessCustomers {

    //...

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", length = 20)
    private BusinessCustomersStatus status;

    //...
}
```

It is in addition more according to the rest of your code.

Regarding your second problem, the application is returning `"status":"ACTIVE"` because in [`BusinessCustomersFullDTO`](https://github.com/rcbandit111/Search_specification_POC/blob/main/src/main/java/org/merchant/dto/businesscustomers/BusinessCustomersFullDTO.java) you are defining the status field as `String` and this field receives the result of the [mapping process](https://github.com/rcbandit111/Search_specification_POC/blob/984ebcacfdcc5e61e0091e259bb513e03fc6036f/src/main/java/org/merchant/service/businesscustomers/BusinessCustomersRestServiceImpl.java#L53) performed by `@Mapstruct` and `BusinessCustomersMapper`.

To solve that issue, as I suggested you previously, you can modify your `Mapper` to handle the desired custom conversion:

```java
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.Named;
import org.merchant.config.BaseMapperConfig;
import org.merchant.database.entity.BusinessCustomers;
import org.merchant.database.service.businesscustomers.BusinessCustomersStatus;
import org.merchant.dto.businesscustomers.BusinessCustomersFullDTO;

@Mapper(config = BaseMapperConfig.class)
public interface BusinessCustomersMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "status", target = "status", qualifiedByName = "businessCustomersToDTOStatus")
    BusinessCustomersFullDTO toFullDTO(BusinessCustomers businessCustomers);


    @Named("busineessCustomersToDTOStatus")
    public static String businessCustomersToDTOStatus(final BusinessCustomersStatus status) {
        if (status == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return status.getStatus();
    }
}
```

If you do not prefer this solution, perhaps you can take a different approach: it will consist in the following. The idea is modifying the Jackson serialization and deserialization behavior of `BusinessCustomersFullDTO`. In fact, in your use case only is necessary to modify the serialization logic.

First, define the `status` field in `BusinessCustomersFullDTO` in terms of `BusinessCustomersStatus` as well:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class BusinessCustomersFullDTO {

    private long id;

    private String name;

    private String businessType;

    private BusinessCustomersStatus status;

    private String description;

    private String country;

    private String address1;
}
```

To complete the solution, please, perform the following changes in the `BusinessCustomersStatus`  enum:

```java
public enum BusinessCustomersStatus {
    A("active"),
    O("onboarding"),
    NV("not_verified"),
    V("verified"),
    S("suspended"),
    I("inactive");

    private String status;

    BusinessCustomersStatus(String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    // Define the status field as the enum representation by using @JsonValue
    @JsonValue
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    // Use the fromStatus method as @JsonCreator
    @JsonCreator
    public static BusinessCustomersStatus fromStatus(String status) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(status)) {
            return null;
        }

        switch (status) {
            case "active": {
                return A;
            }

            case "onboarding": {
                return O;
            }

            case "not_verified": {
                return NV;
            }

            case "verified": {
                return V;
            }

            case "suspended": {
                return S;
            }

            case "inactive": {
                return I;
            }

            default: {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                        String.format("Unkhown status: '%s'", status)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the inclusion of the `@JsonValue` and `@JsonCreator` annotations: the later is using for deserialization which seems unnecessary to me in your application, but just in case.

Please, see the [relevant documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) of the provided Jackson annotations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think that into `BusinessCustomersFullDTO` the line `private BusinessCustomersStatus status;` should be `private String status;` in order to perform search by several values?

Comment: Hi @PeterPenzov. No please, don't mix the two concepts. On one hand, you have `BusinessCustomersSearchParams`, and in this dto the `status` field is represented as a `List` to allow you for filtering by different values. But here, in `BusinessCustomersFullDTO` you have a single result. As it seems you prefer to not change you mapper, just keep `status` as `BusinessCustomersStatus status` and use the suggested `@JsonValue` and `@JsonCreator` annotations. Please, could you try and see?

Answer (score 2):

Notice your `convertToDatabaseColumn()` method in `BusinessCustomersStatusAttributeConverter`.

It should return `value.name()` instead of `value.getStatus()`.

Comment: Looks like now I need to change something else? I get `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown status: 'ACTIVE'` probably here? https://github.com/rcbandit111/Search_specification_POC/blob/main/src/main/java/org/merchant/database/service/businesscustomers/BusinessCustomersStatus.java#L22

Comment: You don't need the status member at all, so you can just delete it. Simply use the .name() method of the ENUM, or generally better, delete your whole custom converter and use the annotation @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) as @pleft explains in his comment

Comment: @PeterPenzov So that means you have defined the `enum` in the database in lower case. So you've gone to all this trouble to get lowercase. Why exactly do you think you need to change your mind about all that?

Comment: Because I wan to store in DB only `A` and return to UI `active` value.

Comment: @PeterPenzov So you need to change your converter, your database, everything. What you've done is actually back to front from what you now say you need.

Comment: yes, I will post a new question.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Why? Same question, same answer.

Comment: ok, can you show me how I need to modify the code in order to get the `A` value only into database but to send and receive String `active`?

Comment: @PeterPenzov change the switch statement to use `switch (status.toLowerCase())` instead of `switch (status)`

Comment: Can you propose me some better solution, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov You mean better than a correct one? Why?

Comment: @PeterPenzov What do you mean about a better solution? What is wrong with my solution? Or are you not asking me?

Comment: @davidalayachew can you show me how to store `A` into database but to return `active`?

Comment: @PeterPenzov that is what I was trying to do. If you use the switch case I gave you, combined with the information that user207421 and PeterBivolarski gave you, you should have a working solution that stores `A` into the database, but returns `active`. We need you to try that and let us know what happens when you try it, so that we can better help you.

Comment: I tried the code but I get `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown status: 'A'`

Comment: Which method threw the exception? And at what line? @PeterPenzov

Comment: Better yet, can you share the stack trace? If it's too big, edit your original question to include it, then post a comment here letting us know.